# Why is a file having 0 hard links?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, cifs, hardlink

I need to access a file using Java and I get `NoSuchFileException`.

The file seems to have 0 hard links. The file however has an associated `inode` number.
I am able to use the `inode` number to find the hard links using `find . -inum NUM`. The filesystem is `cifs`.

I am really confused why the hard links is showing as 0 when I check with `ls -l` and how I can set the file links back to `1`?

Output of `ls -lh`:
[image: Image 1]

Output of `ls -i`:
[image: Image 2]

Comment: which filesystem is it?

Comment: @golimar It says cifs

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski cifs. No, I read `fsck` could result in data loss.

Comment: It doesn't matter now because (I believe) one cannot `fsck` cifs. Please [edit] the question and clearly state it's about cifs. Tell us the mount options you're using.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski How can I check the mount options?

Comment: I would very much not expect the hard-link count to be accurate on a network share. I suggest you log into the file server, if at all possible, and check the situation there.

Comment: @DanielB It's not possible. I only have access to the ubuntu system to which the cifs drive is mounted.