# File exists in directory, but not able to access it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, filesystems, cifs

I am able to see a file in the directory listing using `ls -lh` and it has 75kb file size. However, when I try to view the file using `cat` or move it using `mv`, I get `No such file or directory`.

The file also seems to have `0 hardlink` as seen in `ls -lh`. The filesystem is `cifs`.

`file <filename>` gives `<filename>: writable, executable, regular file, no read permission`. Ideally, it should be giving `<filename>:data` as the output.

Output of `ls -lh`
[image]

Output of `cat <filename>` and `file <filename>`
[image]

How can I fix this issue and access the file?

Comment: The file name might include an invisible blank?

Comment: I am using autocomplete to fill the filename. So I don't think there are invisible characters. Also, it says there is no read permission for the file.

Comment: Enclose the name in quotes when using autocomplete.

Comment: In [your previous question](https://superuser.com/q/1694355/432690) you're asking "how I can set the file links back to 1?"; here "how can I access the file?". The underlying issue is probably the same. It may be a problem on the server (e.g. corrupted filesystem from which cifs reads data).

Comment: @harrymc still getting same error.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yeah. I was hoping there was someway I could fix the file and approaching the problem from a different angle could give me better leads.

Comment: It's possible that the file was deleted but is still accessed by a process. You may check with `fuser filename`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the 0 hard link might be the problem. Your problem with using `cat` against the file [throws the same error](https://www.linuxshelltips.com/hardlinks-and-softlinks-in-linux/) (See "Remove Parent File") as using `cat` against an orphaned link. Links only preserve permissions and ownership, so there is no actual file contents to `cat`. CIFS has had problems with hard links in the past.

Could also be simply improper permissions: try inserting `sudo` before the command or use `chmod` to [change file permissions.](https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html) (Referenced from other comment)

If you do `find / -xtype l`, it will list all broken links (you can change / with your working directory). As to getting the file contents, you can refer [here](https://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-find-all-hard-links-to-a-file-in-linux/)

Comment: Changing permission did not help. [Image1](https://ibb.co/h1QNnxQ)

I took the inum and checked if there is a link to that in the given directory. It showed the file. When I checked for broken links, I got nothing. [Image2](https://ibb.co/z5GtqQz)

Comment: Try `df -ih /` to see if you have enough inodes available-- if you don't you'll need to delete files. Use `stat /home/abcxyz/file` (change filepath) and paste the contents as well. `ls -li` to find the inode number for the file, then use [this](https://linuxfreelancer.com/linux-find-a-file-by-inode-number) to see what comes up.

Comment: `df -ih` gives `/path      0     0     0     - /mnt/prabes`. `stat` gives 
```  File: /mnt/prabes/esdata/nodes/0/indices/h8iZgJQIRECkMf2AJM7pIw/0/index/_383g_Lucene50_0.pos
  Size: 75822      Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1048576 regular file
Device: 32h/50d Inode: 15514076357448433664  Links: 0
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-09-28 12:51:03.784289300 +0000
Modify: 2020-09-28 12:51:03.784289300 +0000
Change: 2020-09-28 12:51:03.784289300 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: So from the output of `df -ih` check `/mnt/prabes` to see if you can get the file from there. If not, then there's really no way to access the file as there are no records to tell the computer where to get the file contents.

Comment: `df -ih` with the file path is returning that it is mounted on `/mnt/prabes`.

Comment: Yes, if you cannot see the file there or any other files, then there's nothing you can do to get the file contents back.

Answer (score 0):

Question, what distro are you running and you mentioned this being a cifs share?  Is that file opened by any other system connecting to the NAS?  I know windows has a nasty habit of not allowing you to read/access files that are in use (at least on WSL)

```
$ ls -lash Default/Network//Cookies
2.3M -rwxrwxrwx 1 period period 2.3M Jan 17 21:30 Default/Network//Cookies

$ file -s !$
file -s Default/Network//Cookies
Default/Network//Cookies: writable, executable, regular file, no read permission

$ sudo cat !$
sudo cat Default/Network//Cookies
cat: Default/Network//Cookies: Permission denied
```

If the file is in use by another system that could very well be the cause of your issue, especially if said other system is a windows system.